# How to Select NOT IN Value (Formula Crystal Reports)

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have this query in SQL server:

```
select * from  ARInvoices ar 
left join ARInvoiceDetails det on ar.InvoiceID = det.InvoiceID
where ar.InvoiceID not in (select InvoiceID from CashReceiptInvoices ) 
and det.SubmitTo = 1 and VoucherStatus = 0 and det.TransactionType = 1
```

I would like to have it thru a Formula in Crystal Reports XI but i'm having a hard time with the not in. I used <> but the results are coming empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know crystal reports at all, but if it's only the `NOT IN` you're having trouble with, but your `LEFT JOIN` works fine, then you could just add another `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select * 
from  ARInvoices ar 
left join ARInvoiceDetails det on ar.InvoiceID = det.InvoiceID
left join CashReceiptInvoices cri on ar.InvoiceID = cri.InvoiceID
where  cri.InvoiceID IS NULL
   and det.SubmitTo = 1 
   and VoucherStatus = 0 
   and det.TransactionType = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the `NOT IN` by using an "anti-join" (a `LEFT JOIN` with a constraint where the column in the table to which you are joining `IS NULL`):

```
select * from  ARInvoices ar 
left join ARInvoiceDetails det on ar.InvoiceID = det.InvoiceID
left join CashReceiptInvoices cri on ar.InvoiceID = cri.InvoiceID -- new JOIN
where cri.InvoiceID is null                                       -- no match
and det.SubmitTo = 1 and VoucherStatus = 0 and det.TransactionType = 1
```

Comment: Excellent. It works Perfect. I go to Crystal and add a new Command thru a new connection. Thanks Cory for your help :)